# Calculate and plot expected value involving summations and products

Tags: beginner, time-limit-exceeded, combinatorics, r

I wrote a code to calculate a series of summations and products for a maths assignment I'm doing. The equation is shown below.

$$E(\sigma)=[1-(P(\text{$1^{st}$ rejects}) \times P(\text{$2^{nd}$ rejects}) \times \ldots \times P(\text{$n^{th}$ rejects}))] \times \frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{(n-j)(n-j+1)}{2}}{j}$$

where

$$P(\text{$x^{th}$ rejects})=1-\left[\frac{j}{n} \times\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{j-1} \times \prod_{y=2}^{x-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} (\binom{j-1}{k}(\frac{n-1}{n})^{j-1-k}(\frac{1}{n})^k(1-\prod_{i=0}^{Y-1} P(i^{th} rejects))) \times \\ \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}(\binom{j-1}{k}(\frac{n-1}{n})^{j-1-k}(\frac{1}{n})^k \sum_{i=0}^{k}(\frac{1}{1+i}\binom{k}{i}(1-\prod_{i=0}^{x-1} P(i^{th} rejects))^{k-i}(\prod_{i=0}^{Y-1} P(i^{th} rejects))^i)))\right]$$

The code calculates \$E(\sigma)\$ for all values of \$j\$ for \$1\le j\le n\$ for all values of \$n\$ for \$3\le n\le a\$. The code finds the value of \$j\$ which produces the highest value of \$E(\sigma)\$ for each \$n\$ and expresses this as a percentage of \$n\$. Then it plots the graph of this percentage versus \$n\$

The thing is it requires many loops and the computation for \$a=100\$ seems like it's taking forever. Is there a way to reduce the computation time? If not, if I leave the computer running for a few hours will it eventually compute successfully? I'm really new to programmming so please excuse the messy code.

\$P(\text{$1^{st}$ rejects})\$ and \$P(\text{$2^{nd}$ rejects})\$ are not calculated in the same loop as the rest of \$P(\text{$x^{th}$ rejects})\$ but rather separately as `prob1r` and `prob2r` respectively as putting them in the same loop creates some problems (such as `for y in 2:1`).

Edit: I looked around and discovered the magic of parallelization. By simply changing my `for` loop to a paralllelized `foreach` loop, time taken decreased from `Time difference of 58.93389 secs` to `Time difference of 16.01991 secs` for \$n=40\$. Still, help will be appreciated if further reduction can be achieved as I want to calculate to as high a value of \$n\$ as possible.

```
a=as.numeric(a)

registerDoParallel(cores=3)
z=matrix(nrow=1, ncol=a)

y=(foreach(n=3:a, .combine='c') %dopar%
{
  q=matrix(nrow=1,ncol=n)
  for(j in 1:n)
  {
    m=matrix(nrow=1,ncol=n)
    prob1r=0
    for (k in 0:(j-1))
    {
      prob1r=prob1r+(((dbinom(k,(j-1),(1/n))))*(1/(k+1)))
    }
    m[1,1]=1-((j/n)*prob1r)
    prob2r=0
    for(k in 0:(j-1))
    {
      probir=0
      for (i in 0:k)
      {
        probir=probir+((dbinom(i,k,m[1,1])))*(1/(1+i))
      }
      prob2r=prob2r+((dbinom(k,j-1,(1/n))))*probir
    }
    m[1,2]=1-((j/n)*(((n-1)/n)^(j-1))*prob2r)
    for(h in 3:n)
    {
      prob1=1
      for(y in 2:(h-1))
      {
        prob=0
        proby1=1
        for(k in 1:(y-1))
        {
          proby1=proby1*m[1,k]
        }
        for(k in 0:(j-1))
        {  
          prob=prob+((dbinom(k,j-1,(1/n))))*((1-proby1)^k)
        }
        prob1=prob1*prob
      }
      prob2=0
      for(k in 0:(j-1))
      {
        probrej=1
        for (g in 1:(h-1))
        {
          probrej=probrej*(m[1,g])
        }
        probi=0
        for (i in 0:k)
        {
          probi=probi+((dbinom(i,k,probrej)))*(1/(1+i))
        }
        prob2=prob2+((dbinom(k,j-1,(1/n))))*probi
      }
      m[1,h]=1-((j/n)*(((n-1)/n)^(j-1))*prob1*prob2)
    }
    probno=1
    for(p in 1:n)
    {
      probno=probno*(m[1,p])
    }
    q[1,j]=(1-probno)*((((n*(n+1))/2)-(((n-j)*(n-j+1))/2))/j)
  }
  z[1,n]=((which.max(q))/n)*100
})
x=3:a
lm.r=lm(y~x)

plot(x,y)
abline(lm.r)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please tell us more about the task to be accomplished so that we don't have to reverse-engineer your code to guess your intentions. See [ask].